# Symfony 4 ORM : An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver

Tags: php7, symfony4

Решил ознакомится с Базой данных и доктринами ORM в symfony 4.Дойдя до создания базы **bin/console doctrine:database:create** вылетает ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью composer установил нужные *require* из инструкции.

Сервер настроен: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Wamp64*: **CLI = 7.2.7 - WEB = 5.6.35**

.env :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка была решена настройкой php.ini.

1. Вот список включенных .dll:

`extension=mysqli`;
`extension=pdo_mysql`;
`extension=pdo_odbc`;
`extension=pdo_pgsql`;
`extension=pdo_sqlite`;
`extension=pgsql`;
`extension=shmop`;

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt install php-mysql

з.ы. включение библиотек не помогло

Comment: _включение библиотек не помогло_, не подскажите, что это значит?

Answer (score -2):

Просто установите php-sqlite следующей командой

```
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3
```

Comment: На том сайте принято писать по русски.

Comment: 1. вопрос явно про ms/windows, а ответ вы даёте для gnu/linux, да ещё и конкретно для дистрибутива debian (и наследников). 2. вообще-то здесь принято писать на русском (нажмите [edit] для исправления ответа).